# How to iter through a column in a dataframe and print each value in each iteration

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

**Question :**

How to iter through a column (rxpattern) in a dataframe and print each value in each iteration.

**rx**

[image]

```
for i in range(0,len(rx)):
    print(rx.loc(i,'rxpatter'))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-d5c90e558b73> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0,len(rx)):
----> 2     print(rx.loc(i,'rxpatter'))

TypeError: __call__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for i in range(len(rx)):
    print(rx['rxpatter'].values[i])

# rx['rxpatter'][0]
# rx['rxpatter'][1]
# rx['rxpatter'][2]
# rx['rxpatter'][3]
# ...
```

DataFrame.loc() doesn't allow you to access the index of the column/row you are accessing, by the way here is the documentation if you want to take a deeper look:
[Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)